# Constructing submanifolds. Did I understand this right?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I just want to know whether I understand the construction of a submanifold in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ properly. Please correct everything that you think could be wrong.

As far as I know so far, it is always possible to get a submanifold in a $\mathbb{R}^m$ by these two methods
a) having charts 
b) having a system of equations with special properties such that its solution is a manifold.

And as far as I see: Every submanifold can be represented by both methods? Is this correct?

Since we only covered method a) in class, I have a couple of questions about method b). Especially I want to see why b) is equivalent to the definition of a submanifold by a).

So let's assume that we want to construct a manifold with dimension $n-m$ as a solution to a system of equations $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, such that $(f_1,...,f_m)(x)=0$. Now our manifold shall live in $\mathbb{R}^n$. What we are looking out for is a regular value. This is a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, such that for all $x \in f^{-1}\{y\}$, the derivative $Df(x)$ is surjective(hence, all x are regular points). For simplicity reasons to apply the implicit function theorem I want to say: $y=0$. In that case, our manifold is given by the set of regular points!

So how is this definition equivalent to the charts? Well, afais this is just the implicit function theorem, because: For EVERY regular point, the nullspace $X$ and its complement $X^\perp$ build up $\mathbb{R}^n=X \times  X^\perp$. Therefore we can say that $f'(x)=(g'(x),h'(x))$ for every point in the submanifold, where the first component shall refer to the nullspace and the second one to the complement, hence $f'(x)=(0,h'(x))$. But for dimensional reasons $h'(x)$ must be invertible(as it is also surjective, since f'(x) is).Therefore the implicit function theorem gives us the local chart around this regular point on the manifold to a local surrounding of the regular value.

Am I understanding this right? I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps  this version of the implicit function theorem may explain  the equivalence you asked for. Suppose $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $F:\bR^n\to \bR^m$ is a smooth map  such that $F(0)=0$ and  the differential of $f$ at $0$ is surjective. Then  we can  find new (nonlinear) coordinates $(x^1,\dotsc, x^n)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $0\in\bR^n$ and new (nonlinear) coordinates  $(y^1,\dotsc, y^m)$   in a neighborhood $V$ of $0\in\bR^m$ such that $F(U)\subset V$ and  these new coordinates  the map $F|_U:U\to V$ has the simple description

$$U\ni  (x^1,\dotsc,x^n)\mapsto (y^1,\dotsc,y^m)=(x^1,\dotsc,x^m)\in V. $$

The zero set  $\{F=0\}\cap U$ is then described by the equalities $x^1=\cdots =x^m=0$, and on this zero set you can find coordinates $(x^{m+1},\dotsc, x^{n})$.